# Abstraction for asynchronous streamed results

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, stream

When doing an asynchronous call, there are multiple ways of passing back the result. A nice abstraction is [`Async`], which allows retrieval of the output value, abandoning ([`cancel`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:cancel)), error checking, combining values together etc.

Is there a similar, nice abstraction for returning an asynchronous stream of results? That is, the called service asynchronously sends multiple values, followed by the final result? Something similar to gRPC's [server-side streaming](http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/c.html#streaming-rpcs).

While *stm* offers channels, queues, etc., they're meant to be infinite, without means for finishing / cancelling.

Probably the closest abstraction that comes to my mind is [`ConduitM Void o IO r`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.9/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t:ConduitM), but this is meant for synchronous computations. Probably it'd be possible to wrap an internal channel in it too to make it asynchronous, but *conduit* seems to be quite a heavy dependency for such purpose.

Comment: You could certainly build a thin abstraction around `WhateverChanYouLike (FancyEnvelope a)` that would allow you to communicate "last element" or "cancel" to consumers. I don't have a sense of what the consumer API you want would look like though. There's also `pipes-concurrency` which I haven't gotten to use.

Comment: I'd go for `pipes` with `pipes-concurrency`.

Comment: Also, any FRP library with an `Event`-like type would do the job